# .NET Core Authorization - Constant 403 on JWT Bearer

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, authorization, jwt, asp.net-core-2.0

I'm attempting to authorize requests to my API which bear a JWT token attached to it, however, none of the tutorials, blog posts, and documentation have helped avoiding a constant `403 - Unauthorized` error.

This is the -skimmed- current configuration:

Class which generates the token: `TokenManagement.cs`:

```
// Add the claims to the token
var claims = new[] {
    new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Sub, credentials.Username),
    new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Jti, Guid.NewGuid().ToString()),
    new Claim("claimName", "claimValue")
};
```

Configuring the services: `Startup.cs` - `ConfigureServices()`:

```
services.Configure<GzipCompressionProviderOptions>(options => options.Level = System.IO.Compression.CompressionLevel.Optimal);
services.AddResponseCompression();

services.AddAuthentication()
    .AddJwtBearer(config => {
        config.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
        config.SaveToken = true;
        config.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters()
        {
            ValidIssuer = "Issuer",
            ValidAudience = "Audience",
            IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(symmetricKey))
        };
});

services.AddAuthorization(options => {
    options.AddPolicy("myCustomPolicy", policy => {
        policy.AddAuthenticationSchemes(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
        policy.RequireClaim("claimName", "claimValue");
    });
});

services.AddMvc();
```

General Configuration: `Startup.cs` - `Configure()`:

```
app.UseAuthentication();

app.Use(async (context, next) => {
    await next();

    if (context.Response.StatusCode == 404 &&
        !Path.HasExtension(context.Request.Path.Value)) {
        context.Request.Path = "/index.html";
        await next();
    }
});

app.UseMvc();

app.UseResponseCompression();

app.UseDefaultFiles();
app.UseStaticFiles();
```

Controller which should be authorized: `ActionsController.cs`:

```
[Authorize(Policy = "myCustomPolicy")]
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class ActionsController : Controller
```

Any request I send to the server (which carries a JWT token with the proper claim), returns as a `403`.

**Any methods which have the `[AllowAnonymous]` attribute, work just fine.**

Is there a way to -at least- debug and see what's going on?

Comment: May be your firewall blocking the request

Comment: Sorry, no firewall. Targetting `localhost` at the moment...

Comment: are you able to call simple API without OAuth secure??

Comment: Yep. Before introducing Authorization, everything worked just fine. In fact, with the non-working authorization set up, if a Controller's method is added the `[AllowAnonymous]` attribute, it still works.

Comment: Well the problem is that Authorization header is not getting passed

Comment: What happens if you remove the `RequireClaim` line but keep the authorization at the scheme level?

Comment: I would recommend using the built-in events to make sure the required claim is present. `config.Events = new JwtBearerEvents { OnTokenValidated = async x => { // put breakpoint here and analyze x.Principal } };`. I'm suggesting this as a `403` means authentication worked, that is, the token was found valid, but an authorization requirement failed.

Comment: @MickaëlDerriey You, sir, are an absolute lifesaver. I managed to debug the authorization process with your tip, and saw the mistake. Will be posting it as an answer right away.

Comment: @JSG_85 What was the issue?

Comment: @Narshe it's been a while, and I don't fully remember, but as memory serves, it had to do with name collision between built-in claim names and custom ones. I think `role` was the culprit. Sorry, but I don't have access to the code-base anymore...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found out that some claim types changed to different values from my identity server config.

for example , In my Identity Server i am using role claim type:

```
  UserClaims = new []
  {
     JwtClaimTypes.Role , user.role // "JwtClaimTypes.Role" yield "role"
  };
```

But when i debuged my web api , the role claim type has changed to (see my snapshot below, under watch section):

```
 "http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/role"
```

---

Solution:

To "workaround" (is this desired behavior?) the issue,  you need to check your claim type
value are planning use in web api, and use the correct claim type value in your policy.

```
 services.AddAuthorization(options =>
 {
    options.AddPolicy("RequireAdmin", policy =>
    {
        
       //policy.RequireClaim(IdentityModel.JwtClaimTypes.Role, "Admin"); // this doesn't work
       policy.RequireClaim(ClaimTypes.Role, "Admin"); //  this work
    });
  });
```

my web api debug snapshot:

[image: screen of policyAssertion]

Answer (score 0):

Try to enable CORS in Startup.cs File

```
public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app) {
    app.UseCors(Microsoft.Owin.Cors.CorsOptions.AllowAll);
    // Rest of code
}
```